# Confuse about jquery post

Tags: php, jquery

I am required to pass a parametre to jquery post and then get it using $_POST method .But it doesnt work this way

```
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? "ok" : "error";
    echo $name;
?>
<button type="button" id="getIt">Tıkla</button>

</body>
</html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#getIt').click(function () {
            $.post( "xx.php", {"name": "xxx"})
            });
       })
</script>
```

Comment: it won't reflects in the page... check your network tab in your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to it. I have re-written the code
In the ajax/jquery code above I set have set variable name to nancy and have also include a form input so that you can also get the concept of sending form input data as well.

**Be sure to connect to internet so as to allow this jquery files to load** or you can replace the jquery.min.js with that of your local

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

here is **index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){


        $('#getIt').click(function(){


    var name = 'nancy moree';
    var nickname = $('#nickname').val();

            if(name==""){

                alert('please Enter name');


            }

     else if(nickname==""){

                alert('please Enter Nickname');


            }

    else{

    $('#loader').fadeIn(400).html('<span>Please Wait, Data is being processed....</span>');

    var datasend = "name="+ name + "&nickname=" +nickname;

            $.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                url:'getit.php',
                data:datasend,
                            crossDomain: true,
                cache:false,
                success:function(msg){

                    //empty nickname box after submission
                    $('#nickname').val('');

                    $('#loader').hide();
                    $('#result').fadeIn('slow').prepend(msg);

                }

            });

            }

        })

    });


    </script>


</head>
<body>
</body>

<div id='loader'></div>
<div id='result'></div>
Enter Nick Name:<input type='text' id='nickname' name='nickname' />
<button type="button" id="getIt">Tıkla</button>

</html>
```

Here is **getit.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["name"])){

echo $name=$_POST["name"];
echo $nicky= $_POST["nickname"];

echo '<br>Success';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP loads the entire page before you do a XMLRequest. That's why you can't visualize the value.

In order to 'visualize' the value/response you can use 'done()' method after ajax call. This would be print the entire text.